# How to tell if there is strong evidence one brand is preferred over another?

Tags: inference

Two new varieties of cheese, V1 and V2, are to be compared. In order to establish if there was a
significant/real overall difference in consumer response to the two varieties, a study was conducted. Fifty
consumers were randomly assigned into two equal groups, Group 1 to taste V1, and Group 2 to taste V2.
Each variety of cheese was scored over ten characteristics, with each characteristic being given a rating
between 1 and 9 (1=strongly dislike, 9 = strongly like). Consumers in Group 1 scored variety V1, and
consumers in Group 2 scored variety V2. The ratings for each consumer were then added to give a total
score for that variety. The total scores from the consumers in each group are given in Table 2 below.

[image]

The question given is "what can you conclude from the 0.006 figure"? The answer is The probability of the difference in the mean scores of V2 – V1 of at least 9.92 occurring by chance is only 0.006. So V2 is
significantly preferred, as 0.006 < 0.05.

I am a bit confused at what the answer means. Does it mean that there is a 0.994 chance that it did not occur due to chance or something else?

Answer (score 2):

**Your data.** First, I digitized your data (approximately) from the dot plots at the top
of your figure and entered them into R. [My version of your data may not be *exactly* correct, but close
enough for what I want to do.]

```
x1 = c(30,38,41,41,42, 43,45,53,53,54, 56,57,63,64,64,
       66,66,67,67,69, 73,83,84,88,90)
x2 = c(48,59,60,61,61, 62,63,65,67,67, 67,68,68,71,71,
       71,74,75,78,79, 79,80,83,84,84)

summary(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  30.00   45.00   63.00   59.88   67.00   90.00 
[1] 16.2694    # SD x1
summary(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   48.0    63.0    68.0    69.8    78.0    84.0 
[1] 9.059985   # SD x2

mean(x2) - mean(x1)
[1] 9.92
```

The scores in the second group were higher by 9.92 points.
So it looks as if Brand 2 was favored over Brand 1. The
question is whether the difference is large enough, considering
the variability in scoring, to be declared 'significantly different'
in a statistical sense.

The scores may not be exactly normally distributed, but there are
several points in favor of assuming they are approximately normal.

- Each score is the sum
  of ten components, and such scores are often approximately normal.
- The dot plots show no marked skewness or extreme outliers.
- Both data vectors `x1` and `x2` are found to be consistent with
  sampling from normal populations, according to a Shapiro-Wilk
  normality test. (In both tests, P-values are far above $0.05).$

.

```
shapiro.test(x1)$p.val
[1] 0.5010366
shapiro.test(x2)$p.val
[1] 0.4639407
```

**Welch one-sided, two-sample t test.** Therefore, it seems reasonable to use a two-sample t test to judge
whether the observed difference of 9.92 is statistically significant.
Because the sample standard deviations of `x1` and `x2` are somewhat different,
I will use a Welch 2-sample t test, which accommodates samples with different
variability. The null hypothesis is that the two populations have equal
means $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ and the one-sided alternative is that the first
group has a smaller mean than the second $H_a: \mu_1 < \mu_2.$

```
t.test(x1,x2, alte="less")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -2.6635, df = 37.579, p-value = 0.005661
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
      -Inf -3.639094
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
    59.88     69.80
```

The verdict whether or not to reject $H_0$ has to be stated in terms of
the *data* because we have access to the data (and have no way of knowing
exact values of population means $\mu_1, \mu_2.)$

The P-value $0.005661$ of the test indicates that the difference between the
sample means is relatively large. If the population means were equal (as
stated by $H_0,$ then there are fewer than 6 chances in 1000 that we would observe
such a large difference (or a larger one) between sample means.

By 'relatively', I mean that the sizes and variability of the samples have
been taken into account in assessing how to interpret the size of the difference
between sample means.  [If you like, you can take a look at the formula for
the t statistic and its degrees of freedom `df`: you will see sample sizes
$n_1 = n_2 = 25$ and sample standard deviations $S_1 and S_2$ in these formulas.]

The image in your Question shows the P-value $0.006$ which indicates that if population means were equal as large a difference (or larger) between sample means as we have observed would occur very rarely. That's 6 chances in 1000; not *exactly* the same as for the Welch t test I showed above, but both P-values strongly indicate rejection of $H_0$ in favor of $H_1.$
It is common to test hypotheses at the 5% level, which means that 1 chance in 20
is often considered strong enough evidence to reject $H_0.$

If there is a question whether the assumptions for a t test are met, statisticians
look for other ways to find a P-value that will use sample sizes and variabilities
of the two samples to judge whether an observed difference is large enough to be
called 'statistically significant'.

**Permutation test.** In your question it seems that a permutation test is used to find a useful P-value.
You can read about permutation tests in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29), which gives some of their history and shows several elementary examples. There are many kinds of permutation tests and
from your question I can't tell which of them was done; only the results are shown, not the procedure.

So I will do a permutation test of my own, hoping it will give you a general idea what
is involved.

- First, we need a 'metric', a way to measure the difference between the scores in samples `x1` and `x2`. As my metric, I will choose the difference in sample means: $D_\mathrm{obs} = \bar X_2 - \bar X_1.$
- Second, I will perform permutations of the data. Specifically, we have $n_1+n_2 = 50$ scores in the two groups combined. Strictly at random, I will pick 25 of the 50 to put into group 1 and put the remaining 25 into group 2. For each such permutation I will find $D^* = \bar X_2^* - \bar X_1^*$ where the `*`'s mean that permuted groups rather than original groups are used.
- Third, I will do $B = 10,000$ of these permutations of the data and get a $D^*$ from each one of them. Information about the sample sizes and variabilities of the data
  gets used in all of this permuting and averaging. So I will get a useful 'permutation distribution' of the 10,000 $D^*$s.
- Finally, I will compare the permutation of $D^*$s with the original $D_{\mathrm{obs}} = 9.92.$ The proportion of $D^*$s that is larger than or equal to $D_{\mathrm{obs}}$ will be the P-value of the permutation test.

The following R code assumes that the data vectors `x1` and `x2` are already present
in R.

```
d.obs = mean(x2) - mean(x1)
x = c(x1, x2)
g = rep(1:2, each=25)

set.seed(1234)
B = 10^4;  d.prm = numeric(B)
for (i in 1:B) {
 g.prm = sample(g)  # randomly scrambles groups
 d.prm[i] = mean(x[g.prm==2]) - mean(x[g.prm==1])
}
mean(d.prm >= d.obs)
[1] 0.0064

hdr="Permutation Distribution of Group Mean Differences"
hist(d.prm, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v=d.obs, col="red")
```

[image]

The P-value $0.0064$ from my permutation test is about the same as
the P-value from the permutation test in your Question. A permutation
test is a random procedure (depending on random permutations of the
observations into two groups), so results might differ slightly from
one run to another.

In any case my permutation P-value and the one in your Question are
essentially the same. Both are small enough to lead to rejection of $H_0.$